# Maven override files in classpath if folder Y exists

Tags: maven, resources, overriding

I want to add some local config files to the classpath of maven mavenprojekt.
These files "config-local" shall override existing default config file out of my resources dir.
So only when the directory "config-local" exists the default config-files shall be replaced by the local config.

I tried to add the dir as resource to my maven Build, but it doesn't worked and I'm not sure what might happen if the config-local does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was very easy:

Maven Resources Plugin adds the resources in reverse declaration order:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <!-- The resources will be placed in reversed order in the war
          that means first entry will be added as last resource and may override other resources -->
        <resource>
            <!-- ATTENTION! we need the config-local declration at first cause it shall be placed as last resource in the classpath -->
            <directory>config-local</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Just moving the config-local resource on top and it will be added as last resource and may override other default files. 
If the folder not exists Maven will skip it without any problem.